# Export data from sage to odoo (openERP)

Tags: data-migration, odoo-9

We are using sage saari gestion commerciale (Sales management) 100 Pack V8.00 1998. We would like to migrate data (customers, suppliers, invoices...) from sage to odoo (OpenERP).

Can anyone please provide us with the steps to follow to migrate all the data to odoo.

Thanks.